# Are all 2-adic integers even or odd?

Tags: number-theory

I know nothing about p-adic numbers so this may be a simple question. Is the following statement true in the 2-adic integers?

$\forall x\exists y(x=y+y \lor x=y+y+1)$

Comment: Yes, but the analogous thing for $\mathbb Z_p$ for $p>2$ is to ask what the residue modulo $p$ is.

Comment: So do you finally accept that $\forall x\exists y(x=y+y \lor x=y+y+1)$ is a theorem of $MA$, and that $\forall x(\exists y(y+y=x) \overline{\vee} \exists y(y+y+1=x))$ is a theorem in $PA$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Every 2-adic integer $a$ has unique 2-adic expansion
$$a_0+a_1\cdot 2+a_2\cdot2^2+a_3\cdot2^3+\cdots\quad (\text{For each $a_i$ is $\,0\,$ or $\,1\,$}).$$
If $a_0=0$, then $a=2(a_1+a_2\cdot2+a_3\cdot2^2+\cdots)$, and if $a_0=1$ then $a=1+2(a_1+a_2\cdot2+a_3\cdot2^2+\cdots).$

Answer (score 0):

In general for unital rings $R$,

$$\begin{array}{r} \forall x\in R~~\exists y\in R~~(x=y+y~{\rm or}~ x=y+y+1) \\[4pt]
\iff R=2R\cup (1+2R) \\[4pt]
\iff R/2R\cong {\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z}~~{\rm or}~~R/2R\cong\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z. \end{array}$$

We denote $2R:=\{r+r|r\in R\}$. In particular $\,{\Bbb Z}_2/2{\Bbb Z}_2\cong{\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z}$ and ${\Bbb Z}_p/2{\Bbb Z}_p\cong\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z$ if $p\ne2$.

In fact $R/2R\cong\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ iff every element is either even or odd but not both, and $R/2R\cong\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z$ iff every element is both even and odd.